# Finding exact value in 2d array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, regex

I'm trying to find an exact value in a 2D array but it doesn't work. I have no idea where I made a mistake. I need to find only the string "Terminal - Gate:".

Here is my code:

```
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
    var re = new RegExp('\\b(' + "Terminal - Gate:" + ')\\b');
    var checkWord = re.test(data[i][j]);
       if (checkWord){
           console.log(data[i][j]);
           console.log(data.indexOf(data[i]));
           console.log(data.indexOf(data[j]));
       }
  }

}
```

Comment: can you provide a sample of input data? or probably a fiddle or plunker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to find a string that includes `'Terminal - Gate:'`. If this is the case, this should work.

```js
var data = [['abc', 'def'], ['abc', 'def'], ['abc', 'Terminal - Gate:', 'def', 'ghi']];

var i, j;
var found = false;

for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
        if (data[i][j].includes('Terminal - Gate:')) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    if (found) {
        break;
    }
}

if (!found) {
    i = undefined;
    j = undefined;
}

console.log(i, j);
```

It'll stop when it's found and you'll have the correct `i` and `j` values outside the loop. If it's not found, `i` and `j` will both be `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this following regex:

```
var re = new RegExp('\"Terminal - Gate:\"');
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Could you use `.includes()` instead?  Like this...

```
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < data[i].length; j++) {
          if (data[i][j].includes('Terminal - Gate:')){
           console.log(data[i][j]);
           console.log(data.indexOf(data[i]));
           console.log(data.indexOf(data[j]));
          }
  }
}
```